# setTimeout and remove node with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove nodes fetched with an AJAX call with jQuery and then call the done function again in order to get new data.

```js
fetchData();

function fetchData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "info/info.php",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
  }).done(function(data) {
    let total = $("#total");
    let table = $(".table");

    function removeNode() {
      $(".table").remove();
      $("#total").remove();
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      removeNode()
      fetchData()
    }, 30000)
  }).fail(function(response) {
    console.log(response);

  }).always(function(response) { });
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do, but it's not working. Only remove node works in this case and I don't get new data. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: After you run `$(".table").remove();` then `$(".table")` object does not exist anymore

Comment: `done` is called when the request is succesful and gives you the requested data. But it seems you are not processing it in any way

Comment: If you are setting content, you might want to use `.empty()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)) instead of remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you didn't use the data fetched from the backend.
You should put something like:

```
$('#total').html(data.total)
$('.table').html(data.table)
```

You don't need to remove node, you just have to replace its content